# Which expression isn't an old way of speaking: Fell to, Fell on, Fell onto, or Dropped to

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, conversation

My linguistic teacher told me I am speaking like the people who lived hundreds of years ago, when I told him, "The paper fall to the ground when I pass it by," this afternoon.
Please tell me which form below is correct when speaking? In addition, which expression seems more modern **in conversational English**?

1.The paper fell to the ground when I passed by. (fell to)

2.The paper fell on the ground when I passed by. (fell on)

3.The paper fell onto the ground when I passed by. (fell onto)

4.The paper fell onto the ground when I passed by it. (add it behind by)

5.The paper dropped onto the ground when I passed by.

Please select one answer from these 5 **or type another one that you think is better and more appropriate than them**.

Comment: You're asking for a poll, which is not constructive. Voting to close.

Comment: it seems like a poll, but i am not sure if there are some better expressions exist for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You said to your instructor, "The paper fall to the ground when I pass it by." THAT is the sentence that the instructor was objecting to because it is grammatically incorrect, which makes it sound, I guess, like you are an older person who never quite learned English. I'm not 100% sure what the instructor meant by that critique. Nevertheless, any of your five sentences is better than the one that you spoke to your instructor. I personally think Sentence 1 sounds most like what a native speaker would say. Sentence 5 is probably the worst because it makes it sound like the paper moved on its own (dropped onto the ground).